# Java mahout colt collections

Tags: java, collections, hadoop, mahout, colt

under [this link](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/colt-download/releases/), we can see several versions of old colt libraries. I'm wondering what library mahout statistical users use today? I need it for a big data project. Please help. mahouters :) I need to use classes `IntOpenSet` and `IntOpenHashMap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a direct link to the download section for [Mahout](http://www.eng.lsu.edu/mirrors/apache/mahout/).  You are looking for "mahout collections" which contains those libraries and classes.

Comment: Thank you. Have you used these collections?

Comment: I've used them before, not extensively though.